# Finding coefficients $s,k$ for the equation $z=s\sqrt t+kt$

Tags: partial-derivative, physics

We have Philip's equation to evaluate Cumulative Infiltration of water into soil:

$$z=s\sqrt t+kt$$
Where $z$ is Cumulative Infiltration and $t$ is Cumulative time and $s,k$ are coefficients.  Here is the method I've taught to find these coefficients:

> We equate $Q$ with differences of measured infiltration and infiltration from the equation:
> $$Q=s\sqrt t+k.t-z$$
> So for the measurement of the $i$th step we have the following equation w
> $$Q_i=s_i\sqrt{t_i}+k_it_i-z_i$$
> Then to find $s$ , $k$ we need to solve the system of equations obtained form $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial s}=0$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial k}=0$

So I am trying to find the coefficients of $z=s\sqrt t+kt$ for the following datas:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
t& z \\ \hline
 5&2  \\ \hline
 15&  4.5\\ \hline
 45&   9\\ \hline
 75&  13 \\ \hline
 110&   17.5\\ \hline
 \end{array}$$

By following the procedure I got

$$Q_1=s_1\sqrt{5}+5k_1-2$$
$$Q_2=s_2\sqrt{15}+15k_2-4.5$$
$$Q_3=s_3\sqrt{45}+45k_3-9$$
$$Q_4=s_4\sqrt{75}+75k_4-13$$
$$Q_5=s_5\sqrt{110}+110k_5-17.5$$
And  $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial s}=\sqrt {t_i}$ , $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial k}=t_i$ And I didn't get any system of equations . can you please help me? I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ data points $(t_i,z_i)$ and you need to adjust the model $$z=s\sqrt t+kt$$ This is a multilinear regression with predictors $\sqrt t$ and $t$ without constant term.

If your prefer, let $t_i=u_i^2$ to make
$$z= s u +k u^2$$

Just do it with Excel (polynomial trend line).

**Edit**

I shall use the most basic approach using normal equations, having the (may be wrong) feeling that you are not very comfortable with matrices.

In the least-square sense, you want to minimize the sum of squares of absolute errors that is to say
$$\text{SSQ}=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2 \qquad \text{where} \qquad r_i=s\sqrt {t_i}+kt_i- z_i$$  Write the partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial \text{SSQ}}{\partial s}=2 \sum_{i=1}^n r_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial s}=2 \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[s\sqrt {t_i}+kt_i- z_i \Big]\sqrt {t_i} $$
$$\frac{\partial \text{SSQ}}{\partial k}=2 \sum_{i=1}^n r_i \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial k}=2 \sum_{i=1}^n \Big[s\sqrt {t_i}+kt_i- z_i \Big]{t_i} $$ Set these partial derivatives equal to $0$ since you are looking for the minimum and expand to get
$$s\sum_{i=1}^n t_i + k\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^{3/2}-\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^{1/2}z_i=0$$
$$s\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^{3/2} + k\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^n t_iz_i=0$$ So, two linear equations is $(s,k)$. Just solve them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. when I set polynomial of order two I get this equation $y = -0.0003x^2 + 0.1823x + 1.4295$. How can I get rid of $1.4295$?

Comment: Don't you have a *no intercept option* ? Otherwise, use matrix calculations or normal equations.

Comment: Oh I found it. Thanks!

Comment: Although I think it is the best method to find coefficients accurately , but I am preparing for an exam and I don't think I'm allowed to use Excel. So I should somehow use that incomprehensible method I explained.

Comment: Thanks sir :) That's kind of you! I know very basics of matrix calculations like adding or multiplying matrices and so on.

Comment: Hi sir Claude, thanks again for the help. Now after 1.5 year I'm back here again! Now I'm MSc student and and have a similar course with the same professor and he gave us the same problems to practise for exam. Although I'm still not comfortable with matrix calculation (but willing to progress in it), would you please solve the problem with matrices?

Comment: After all, it is really fun to solve such problems with different mathematics tools!